# Why Edge's (on windows) download action triggers very slowly?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

I used to use Chrome, When I click/open some link, the download panel/window opens with no delay. But in Edge, the browser takes a very long time to respond to the click, leading to multiple clicks and repeated downloads:(

Since Edge is based on Chromium, I wonder why it takes so long for Edge to trigger a download and how to fix it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I do not see that behavior here.  Try repairing Edge (Settings, Apps)  and then run DISM / SFC as a first repair step.    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.